# Django CBV handle file upload from form

Tags: django

I've written this form, simple and not linked to a model or Form object (I find it easier this way to style the form and control it's behaviour with js)

```
<form action="{% url 'upload_music_file' %}" method="POST" id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="csv-file">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the CBV that handles the post request

```
class MusicFileUploadView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "music_file_upload.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print( request.FILES.keys() )

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

problem is I don't see the file in the request objects

```
[01/May/2020 08:39:07] "GET /static/img/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4822
dict_keys([])
[01/May/2020 08:39:19] "POST /upload-music-file HTTP/1.1" 200 7266
[01/May/2020 08:39:20] "GET /static/img/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4822
dict_keys([])
[01/May/2020 08:39:28] "POST /upload-music-file HTTP/1.1" 200 7266
dict_keys([])
[01/May/2020 08:41:13] "POST /upload-music-file HTTP/1.1" 200 7266
[01/May/2020 08:41:13] "GET /static/js/upload_file.js?v=1.0.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

there's javascript that checks to see if the file exists and is of the right type before submitting

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#upload-form').submit(function(event){
        csv_file = $('#csv-file').val().endsWith('.csv')
        file_exists = Boolean($('#csv-file').val())

        $('#no-csv-error, #no-file-error').addClass('d-none')
        if (!file_exists) {
            //blank file
            event.preventDefault()
            $('#no-file-error').removeClass('d-none')
            $(this).find('button').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-secondary')
        } else if (!csv_file) {
            //if not a csv file
            event.preventDefault()
            $('#no-csv-error').removeClass('d-none')
            $(this).find('button').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-secondary')
        }
    })
});
```

which means either the form didn't send it or Django CBV implementation I have isn't the right way to find the file.

Comment: Your file input is missing a `name` attribute.

Comment: yup, completely missed that